# getting 404 modal when I do click event on Laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have started using livewire but I can't make it work im using a `wire:click` to load a form either on create mode or edit mode, but when I did click all I got was some sort of modal with 404 error

this is the livewire component

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Activities extends Component
{
    public $view = 'none';

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.activities');
    }

    public function create_view(){

        $this->view = 'create';

    }

    public function edit(){

        $this->view = 'edit';

    }
}
```

this is the view

```
<button wire:click="create_view" class="button-warning">{{ __('Create') }}</button>

@if ($view != 'none')
    <div class="col-span-6">
        @include("livewire.$view")
    </div>
@endif
```

Edit: I load the view manually and it loads correctly, for example:

```
@if ($view != 'none')
    <div class="col-span-6">
        @include("livewire.edit")
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

if like you said this work then you have to check for the $view value. Always that you close the view remember change the property to the default value.

```
@if ($view != 'none')
    <div class="col-span-6">
        @include("livewire.edit")
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be having a Livewire configuration issue. Check your installation and specifically your `asset_url` in your `config/livewire.php` if you have published your config

> php artisan livewire:publish --config

The 404 modal should disappear once your config is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If your livewire.php file in config not best config
this error should not disappear
make asset_url `'asset_url' asset_url => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'` (if you have localhost)

Answer (score 0):

**Change your code like this.**
Because in your code the variable $view will consider part of string. So livewire is searching a page like `livewire.$view`. But in our case we didn't have like that filename. We have only the view file `create`. So change as per the code given below. It will work

```
<button wire:click="create_view" class="button-warning">{{ __('Create') }}</button>

@if ($view != 'none')
    <div class="col-span-6">
        @include('livewire.'.$view)
    </div>
@endif
```